# How to properly clear the internal buffer of a readable stream in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I'm working on my custom transform stream. Since I handle buffering and caching manually, I need to ensure that no chunks will be automatically sent when re-piping it. To achieve that I should clear/reset the internal buffer (the write queue) before attempting to call `.pipe()`.

Since my stream logic is quite complicated, I made this simplified example to help you better understand what I'm trying to solve:

```js
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream')
const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

;(async () => {
    const readable = new Readable()
    readable._read = () => {}

    const writable = new Writable()
    writable._write = (chunk, _encoding, callback) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString())
        callback()
    }

    readable.pipe(writable)
    await wait(100) // This small delay replaces listening to the pipe/unpipe events 

    readable.push('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

    console.log('unpipe')
    readable.unpipe(writable)
    await wait(100)

    readable.push('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')

    // readable.clearInternalBufferOrWhatever() // ???

    console.log('pipe')
    readable.pipe(writable)
    await wait(100)

    readable.push('ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc')
})()

// => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (Expected ✔)
//    unpipe
//    pipe
//    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb (Unexpected ❌)
//    ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc (Expected ✔)
```

As you can see, the writable stream has successfully received the second chunk (`'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'`) and that's what I'm trying to avoid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! Streams have an internal property called `_readableState` which contains the internal buffer. It's possible to clear it with just 2 lines of code:

```js
readable._readableState.buffer.clear()
readable._readableState.length = 0
```

Note that `_readableState` isn't safe since it is internal and undocumented and could get breaking changes at anytime. However, this solution is confirmed to work on node v8.10.0 and v14.17.2.

Here is a full working example:

```js
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream')
const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

;(async () => {
    const readable = new Readable()
    readable._read = () => {}

    const writable = new Writable()
    writable._write = (chunk, _encoding, callback) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString())
        callback()
    }

    readable.pipe(writable)
    await wait(100)
    readable.push('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

    console.log('unpipe')
    readable.unpipe(writable)
    await wait(100)

    readable.push('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')

    readable._readableState.buffer.clear()
    readable._readableState.length = 0

    console.log('pipe')
    readable.pipe(writable)
    await wait(100)

    readable.push('ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc')
})()

// => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
//    unpipe
//    pipe
//    ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

Comment: I have the same problem with implementing a Duplex stream on the writable side. Any solutions for that? And is it safe to mess with the internal stuff since its no where documented?

Comment: I guess yes, unless it's removed from a recent release of node.

Comment: Do you have a solution for writable streams? The properties are not existing on `_writableState`

Answer (score 0):

From Node's stream [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablereadsize) on `readable.read()`:

> If no data is available to be read, `null` is returned.

So if we keep calling `readable.read()` until `null` is returned, then the internal buffer should be emptied.

```js
function clearReadBuffer(readable) {
  while (true) {
    const chunk = readable.read();
    if ( chunk === null ) return;
  }
}
```